# ImportError: cannot import name 'native' from 'OpenSSL._util'

Tags: python, django, openssl

This problem occurs when I run Django.I guss it related with kms-client-sdk==0.1.5

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

You probably miss package or use wrong package (or packages) version.

Read changelogs and try to find the issue (also I recommend using GitHub issues section).
I think also you should post your exact error trace, because that gives possibility to find the certain broken library.